# Inno Setup Unknow Filename Prefix

Tags: installation, directory, inno-setup

I'm trying to set the output folder of the compiled installer to the desktop.
This script can be runned by multiple people across multiple computers, that's why I need to use a dynamic script.

```
OutputDir= "{#Desktop}"
```

I'm able to use the prefix `userdocs:` but not `userdesktop:`.

```
//Works:
#define Path "userdocs:Visual Studio 2013\Projects\"
//Throws "Unknow filename prefix userdesktop:"
#define Desktop "userdesktop:";
```

[Here is the documentation:](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts)

```
{userdesktop} & {commondesktop} *
The path to the desktop folder.

{userdocs} & {commondocs}
The path to the My Documents folder.
```

I also tried `commomdesktop:` with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case you may want to use [`ISSI`](http://members.home.nl/albartus/inno/index.html) and its [`Constants`](http://members.home.nl/albartus/inno/index.html#ISSI_Functions/issi_constants.htm).

```
#define ISSI_IncludePath "..\Inno Setup 5\ISSI\" ;path to ISSI
#include ISSI_IncludePath+"\_issi.isi"

[Setup]
OutputDir={#ISSI_myUserDesktop}
```

Comment: Thanks! So they are storing the `{userdesktop}` constant into the INI file when it's installed. Hm, now remains to hope that the desktop logical folder cannot be relocated.

Comment: They are calling `{userdesktop}` before compiling the real script. ISSI is like kind of preprocessor - it launches own ISS at the start of compilation and stores values what allows to call them in the real script. That is causes some possible issues if you include specific `[Code]` functions in your Script which are previously run in ISSI. But there is solution for that problem too. So the method is not flawless, but it works fine - just have to be aware of limitations and possible issues.

Comment: I thought it happens when you install that ISSI itself. Well, if that works as a preprocessor, then it should be fine. Otherwise you might do the same. You could store the path into an INI file on each machine and read it by preprocessor.